# Why SQL Server 2014 uses an index scan operation for a query with a window function in a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a table containing about 5 million rows with an indexed column (for example, [X]). When I try to get a value from the [X] column of a specified row along with a value from the previous row in accordance with the order specified by the index, I get an inefficient actual execution plan with fat pipes.

[image: actual execution plan fat pipes... lol]

Here is a simplified example.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Val INT);

INSERT INTO #tbl 
    (Val) 
SELECT TOP 1000000
    a.object_id 
FROM 
    sys.all_objects AS a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.all_objects AS b 

SELECT 
    Id, Val, PrevId 
FROM 
    (SELECT *, PrevId = LAG(Id) OVER(ORDER BY Id) FROM #tbl) AS t 
WHERE 
    ID = 42069;

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

Is there a better solution?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, what you referenced an indexed table, but the only tables you use in the query is the system objects `sys.all_objects` (where you return **every** row twice, resulting in 2 scans) and then the **unindexed** temporary table `#tbl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Val INT);

INSERT INTO #tbl 
    (Val) 
SELECT TOP 1000000
    a.object_id 
FROM 
    sys.all_objects AS a 
    CROSS JOIN 
        sys.all_objects AS b 

SELECT t.*, rez.PrevId
FROM #tbl t
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ti.Id as PrevId 
                 FROM #tbl ti 
                 WHERE ti.id < t.id 
                 ORDER BY ti.id desc) rez
WHERE t.Id = 42069

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

Since you intend to return a single row (because you know the Id field is a Primary Key), why not tell the sub-query to return just one row?

New query plan (with slim pipes):

[image]

Giving this additional information will help the Optimizer pick a better plan (actually, it helps it do two Clustered Index Seeks, instead of a Full Clustered Index Scan).

I tried to re-write my query so that it uses the Index as much as possible. Even though the two queries are semantically identical, not using **LAG** will give the optimizer a better idea on how to make a better execution plan.

If you **most definitely want to use LAG**, then I think the most efficient query you can write (**which is slightly less efficient that the version above**) is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
    , PrevId = LAG(Id) OVER(ORDER BY Id) 
FROM #tbl t 
WHERE t.Id <= 42069
ORDER BY t.Id desc
```

Which gives you this execution plan:

[image]

The performance stats of this query can be found in the screenshot below (**green is best overall, orange is best when using LAG**):

[image]

I have tried various options to solve this, which you can see above, which all gave better results, starting from your query (which uses **LAG**), however this above (and last) version gives out the best performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I rewrote my query using OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY because of the first row which has no previous value.

Comment: @Quanysh yes, that's probably the better idea. Please don't forget an upvote/mark answer as correct, if this helped you (it's what keeps us going).